# Ethernet not working on Arch Linux

Tags: linux, networking, arch-linux

I cannot connect to the internet on Linux. I am on Arch Linux. I have had this install for a couple of months now. I decided to reinstall windows alongside arch and then, after finishing that, my Ethernet would not work. I have been using my phone to connect to the internet through wired tethering. It has been working fine, but it is quite slow. systemd-networkd and dhcpcd are both enabled and started. How would I fix this issue?

output of `dmesg | grep -i "network"`:

```
$ dmesg | grep -i "network"
[    2.376157] drop_monitor: Initializing network drop monitor service
[    6.220321] systemd[1]: Listening on Network Service Netlink Socket.
```

output of `ip link`:

```
$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b4:2e:99:a3:63:97 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```